# Securing a class file in Android Project

Tags: java, android, c++, jar, android-ndk

Kindly help me out with a method by which I can hide the code of a class file in Android Studio from other developers. The other developers can access the functions but they won't be able to see the code inside of that class.

This idea comes from iOS, using a compiled static library. iOS uses a pre-compiled static library with which the developers can only access the functions and get the return values.

Reference Link for NDK static library: [Use of prebuild static Library compiled with Android Toolchain](https://tariqzubairy.wordpress.com/2012/03/12/use-of-prebuild-static-library-compiled-with-android-toolchain/)

I don't want to use Android NDK for doing this, I am sure Android SDK is capable of doing this on its own.

Using jar file can be a option, but jar can't hide the code. The class files can easily be decompiled and the code will be exposed to everyone.

Comment: Why you want hide code from other developer?

Comment: The static library or the class will contain a function/algorithm which can't be given to third party developers exposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a long list of [obfuscation tools for android](http://www.google.coml/q=obfuscation%20tools%20for%20android), beginning with [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/tools/help/proguard.html) which is part of the SDK.

Still, none of these achieves the level of protection you get by using a native library with NDK. But even the latter can not be completely protected from disassembling and reverse engineering. It can not be a substitute to legal protection, like patents and copyrights.

Comment: So, am I left with only one option 'NDK'?

Comment: It's all the question of balancing the price of your effort with the price of expected damage.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please suggest me any tutorial, library for making static library(.so) using NDK to use it with my Android Project.
Any input will be helpful.

Comment: You could start with *accepting my answer ;)* and going to ftp://ftp.fixme.ch/free_for_all/Ebook/IT%20eBooks/Software%20Engineering/Mobile/Android/Android%20NDK.PDF

Comment: Any tutorial or any shared library example would have helped me a lot.

Anyways  Thanks Alex.

Comment: NDK itself comes with a bunch of samples, but they cannot replace a good book

Answer (score 0):

The only way to really completely hide it is to host the code in a web service.  And that would probably be easier than learning NDK coding, though it obviously has other drawbacks.

Comment: I would have to do this on the front-end side itself as the iOS apps are capable of doing this using Static Shared Libraries.
The server is common for both the platforms.

Comment: Another advantage is that a carefully designed library can be written once and compiled as static library for both iOS and Android, isolating all platform-specific details in a JNI and Objective-C wrappers, respectively